# Is correct to use @OneToMany with @OneToOne?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a class `Portfolio` where the debts that the debtors have with different banks are kept. Therefore, a portfolio has a list of `Debt` objects and the annotation is `@OneToMany`.

This is `Portfolio`:

```
@Entity
public class Portfolio extends PersistentEntity {
    @OneToMany
    private List<Debt> debts;

    /* Getters and setters */
}
```

And the class `Debt`:

```
@Entity
public class Debt extends PersistentEntity {
    @OneToOne
    private Portfolio portfolio;

    /* Getters and setters */
}
```

My question is what annotation to use in the `Debt` class. I understand it is `@OneToOne` because a debt belongs to a particular portfolio, but I was advised to use `@ManyToOne`. What I understand from this annotation is that a debt can be referenced by different portfolios. Is this correct?

Comment: The opposite end of a one-to-many relationship is many-to-one. There are "many" debts to "one" portfolio. From the perspective of a single debt, it is one debt to one portfolio, but in reality, the relationship in the debt class is representative of the relation as a whole.

Comment: Many `Debt`s belong to a single 'Portfolio` so @ManyToOne in `Debt`.  It's about the overall relationship between the entities, and not about a particular instance of a `Debt`.

Comment: Perfect! But if I use `@OneToOne`, does an error occur (in addition to the conceptual misunderstanding)? I ask you because I was using it with `@OneToOne` but it did not throw any error, so it may be that errors do not arise or that I have forgotten to implement something and those errors do not appear to me.

Comment: a good read on some JPA relationships: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113885/difference-between-one-to-many-many-to-one-and-many-to-many

Answer (score 2):

You should use annotation @ManyToOne.
In your case, as you said Portfolio has a list of Debt objects and the annotation is @OneToMany.
On the other hand, each Debt can belong ONLY ONE Portfolio, so you should use annotation @ManyToOne

Also, see these links:

- [Hibernate mapping: OneToMany and OneToOne on child object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647584/hibernate-mapping-onetomany-and-onetoone-on-child-object-property)
- [When to use, not to use, OneToOne and ManyToOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263589/when-to-use-not-to-use-onetoone-and-manytoone)
- [Difference Between One-to-Many, Many-to-One and Many-to-Many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113885/difference-between-one-to-many-many-to-one-and-many-to-many)
- https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-one-1.html

Comment: The annotation in the two classes is used when we want a bidirectional relationship, right? If I do not care that the debt has a portfolio reference, I only use `@ OneToMany` in `Portfolio`, right?